# tcolorbox: Figures in-between boxes prevent skips from collapsing

Tags: tcolorbox, vertical-spacing

When a `tcolorbox` specifies an `after skip`, and a following box specifies a `before skip`, they both can “collapse”, e.g. if both are 1cm, the total skip will only be 1cm, not 2cm.
Internally, this is done by using `\addvspace` to insert the spacing.

Unfortunately, having a `figure` environment in between two `tcolorbox` instances, or in between two `\addvspace` macros, prevents the space from collapsing. This causes inconsistent spacing:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{before skip=5mm, after skip=5mm}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    This is a box.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    This is another box.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering\Large This is a figure.
\end{figure}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    This is a third box.
\end{tcolorbox}

This is some text.

\addvspace{5mm}
\addvspace{5mm}

This is more text.

\addvspace{5mm}
\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering\Large This is a figure.
\end{figure}
\addvspace{5mm}

This is the final text.

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of the document]

An obvious solution is to not use this space collapsing at all, reverting to `\vspace`. In the case of `tcolorbox`, this can be done with something like `before=\vspace{5mm}`.

But the space collapsing is useful as it keeps the spacing more visually consistent if boxes are sometimes followed by text, sometimes by more boxes. Is there a way to prevent figures from changing the spacing while keeping space collapsing on?

Comment: If you place almost **anything** (e.g. `\null`) between two `\addvspace`s, they act like `\vspace`s .   Okay, `\unskip` will work.